# replace all references to a drive inside the jobs to another drive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, jobs, dmv, metadata

I have a server where [all my sql server backups](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) are currently being saved to the G: drive.

Now there is no enough disk space on drive G: to keep backups for the last 5 days.
I have asked to add another 100 GB to this G: drive but that was not possible, so they gave me another drive instead, the I: drive with extra disk space, as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

Now I need to replace all the references to the G: drive in the sql server jobs below to point to the new I: drive.

[image]

Suppose I have 3 servers in the same situation, how can I achieve this by T-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this cursor approach to read rows from [dbo.sysjobsteps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobsteps-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and execute [sp_update_jobstep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-jobstep-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) after doing a search/replace for the string you want to change.

This could also be improved to ONLY update job steps that actually have the string.

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @step_id INT
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(max)

DECLARE _CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT job_id
    ,step_id
    ,command
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps

OPEN _CURSOR

FETCH NEXT
FROM _CURSOR
INTO @job_id
    ,@step_id
    ,@command

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @command = replace(@command, 'g:', 'I:')

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep @job_id = @job_id
        ,@step_id = @step_id
        ,@Command = @command

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM _CURSOR
    INTO @job_id
        ,@step_id
        ,@command
END --End While

CLOSE _CURSOR

DEALLOCATE _CURSOR
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness (since from your screenshot, you are using Ola's backup solution), the newer version of Ola's script has the [ability to specify directory structure](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html#DirectoryStructure)

> Default directory structure: {ServerName}${InstanceName}{DirectorySeparator}{DatabaseName}{DirectorySeparator}{BackupType}*{Partial}*{CopyOnly}

The issue - [DatabaseBackup - configurable folder names](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/14) is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could update `msdb..sysjobsteps` table:

```
UPDATE s
SET command = Replace(command, 'G:\', 'I:\')
FROM msdb..sysjobsteps s
    JOIN msdb..sysjobs o ON s.job_id = o.job_id
WHERE o.[name] LIKE 'DatabaseBackup%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one to script the jobs you required and alter the drive location which can be done through SSMS. Click on jobs in sql server agent.

[image]

Then click view object explorer details or press <kbd>F7</kbd>. 
[image]

Once you are in that window do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd>  for the required jobs

and select `script jobs` then click on `drop and create`. 
[image]

This will create a drop and create scripts for all the jobs in a single script. Once this is generated you can review it and change the drive location to new one manually or do a `Find and Replace` in SSMS.
Run the script so new jobs are created with the required params.