# Script SQL Server Agent jobs to file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I am busy making a backup of all Agent Jobs by scripting them all to file.`How would i rewrite the below to use BCP instead

```
        BEGIN
        SET @EchoCommand = 'ECHO ' + @EchoField + ' >> ' + @Path
        + @JobName
        + REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), GETDATE()), ' ',
        ''), ':', '') + '.sql'
```

Something similar to the below

```
        SET @EchoCommand = 'bcp 
        "exec['+DB_NAME()+'].dbo.CreateBackUpFromJob' +
        @JobName + '" queryout "\\ServerName\SQL_Backups\' + @JobName + 
        '.sql" -c -UTF8 -T -SLOCALSERVER'
```

Comment: another option is using object explorer details,https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214614/10267

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to script out SQL Server Agent Jobs using `Powershell` (if that is an option).  The following is an example of how you can use `Powershell` to script the Agent Jobs and also delete previous scripted jobs that were created over a number of days ago.  This script generates a file per Agent Job

You can play around with the code to see if it meets your needs.

```
# Set sql server 
$Instances = "localhost"

foreach($Instance in $Instances)
    {
    # Create sql server and db objects
    $srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $Instance;


    # Write out the job names 
    #$srv.JobServer.jobs|foreach-Object {Write-Host "$_.name" }


    # Script out the Jobs
    $CurrentDate = get-date -f "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $Instance = $Instance.Replace("\","-") + "-" + $CurrentDate
    $srv.JobServer.jobs|foreach-Object {$_.script() > "C:\Temp\SqlJobs\$Instance-$_.txt"}
    }


# Purge files older than 2 weeks
$cutoff = (get-date).AddDays(-14)
dir "C:\Temp\SqlJobs\"|Get-ChildItem -incl '*.txt' -rec|Where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $cutoff -and !$_.PSIsContainer}|remove-item
```

Comment: @ Scott Hodgin is there a way to have each job in an individual output?

Comment: @Vorster - I updated my example to generate a separate script file for each SQL Agent Job.  You can play around with the format of the generated file name.